# Outlook 365 won't open

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-outlook-2019

I have Office 365 and use Outlook 2019.  Last night Outlook was working fine, but this morning I turned on the laptop and Outlook won't open - Windows was in sleep/hibernate mode, so I just clicked on the open Outlook icon, and it just showed up as a small bar at the top, then closed. Trying to open it again does the same thing - just a small bar at the top of the screen, then closes.

[image]

I have restarted the laptop, and held <kbd>Shift</kbd> to try a different profile (I thought this might start in safe mode, but it didn't), and the other profile does the same thing.

I did the Repairs from Settings > Apps, but this has made no difference (I tried both the Quick Repair and the Online Repair)

[image]

Other Office 365 apps are working fine - Word and Excel are two I use often and they start without issue.

**What could be causing this, and how can I get my Outlook to run again?**

If needed, I'm running Windows 10 Pro (version 1903) and Microsoft Office 365 (version 16.0.12105.20000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it.  I found online that the way to start Safe Mode was to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when clicking on the icon.

Once I chose to start in Safe Mode, I started seeing dialogs I wasn't seeing before - It was asking for login details for the email accounts I had in Outlook.  At the same time I received text notification on my phone from Microsoft saying I needed to get new App passwords.  I obtained new App passwords from office.com and pasted them into the login dialogs, and Outlook proceeded to open (into Safe Mode) without issue.

I closed Outlook safe mode, and restarted into regular mode, and it now offered a Microsoft login screen for one of the accounts - I entered the regular password for this account (not the App password) and Outlook opened no problem.  A close and reopen worked as normal again (no login required this time).

So it appears that Outlook had somehow lost the connection to an account, but couldn't show the dialog for some reason.  After proceeding through Safe Mode and updating the App passwords everything is working again.

Comment: Just an FYI, Outlook 365 should no longer require app passwords, as it supports Microsoft SSO [**S**ingle **S**ign **O**n), and I believe it supports Google's SSO but I could be misremembering.

Comment: For future reference when others visit this page.....https://www.lifewire.com/outlook-wont-open-4177980

Comment: @JW0914 While connecting into Safe Mode it would not accept the regular password, and I received the text from MS saying I needed a new App password.  Once I quit and restarted into the normal mode the regular password worked as expected.